# how to calculate total number of saturday and sunday between two dates in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    floor(
        datediff('2016-08-01','2016-07-01') / 7) * 2 + (
        CASE WHEN
        IF (weekday('2016-08-01') >= 5, 4,weekday('2016-08-01')) >=
    IF (weekday('2016-07-02') >= 5, 4,weekday('2016-07-01')) 
    THEN

            IF (weekday('2016-08-01') >= 5, 4,weekday('2016-08-01')) -
            IF (weekday('2016-07-01') >= 5, 4,weekday('2016-07-01'))
        ELSE
            5 +
            IF (weekday('2016-08-01') >= 5, 4,weekday('2016-08-01')) -      
            IF (weekday('2016-07-01') >= 5, 4, weekday('2016-07-01'))
        END
    ) weekdays;
```

when i execute this code it always return 9 i don't know where i am doing mistake please suggest me where am doing wrong. while between Saturday and Sunday between given date should be 10 please suggest me

Comment: Please add your expected output based on some sample input. Don't just paste your running query.

Comment: i want when ever we put two date like 2016-08-01 and 2016-07-01  then it should return all Saturday Sunday between  given date

Comment: Do you have any table having all the dates?

Comment: yes i have  table in which have start-date and end date  like this '2016-08-01', '2016-07-01'

Comment: Not only the start date and end date but also the the dates between this range are required. Do you have those too?

Comment: '2016-08-01', '2016-07-01'   we want count Saturday Sunday between given date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have a table having all the dates between your start date and end date (inclusive) then you need to adopt a query which will create all the dates between your given date range (inclusive) first. Then use `WEEKDAY` function of `MySQL` to check whether the day is `Saturday` or `Sunday`

```
SELECT 
dateTable.Day,
DAYNAME(dateTable.Day) AS dayName
FROM 
(   SELECT ADDDATE('2016-07-01', INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS DAY
    FROM (
        SELECT a.a
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
    ) a
    JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
    WHERE 
    @i < DATEDIFF('2016-08-01', '2016-07-01')

) AS dateTable
WHERE WEEKDAY(dateTable.Day) IN (5,6)
ORDER BY dateTable.Day;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/70822/0)</kbd>

**Note:**
<kbd>[`WEEKDAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday)</kbd> returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).

**EDIT:**

If you need only `count`:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS total
FROM 
(   SELECT ADDDATE('2016-07-01', INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS DAY
    FROM (
        SELECT a.a
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
    ) a
    JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
    WHERE 
    @i < DATEDIFF('2016-08-01', '2016-07-01')

) AS dateTable
WHERE WEEKDAY(dateTable.Day) IN (5,6)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/70824/0)